# Backbone: Update not calling callback function

Tags: backbone.js

I'm trying to add the functionality to my app so I can update my database and then update the DOM.  The database gets updated fine, but the DOM doesn't.  Here is part of my view:

```
 App.Views.Table = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'span',
    initialize: function(options) {
        this.model.on('change', this.render, this);
        this.model.on('update', this.remove, this);

        this.template = this.options.template;
        this.url = this.options.url;
    },
    events: {
        'click .verify': 'verify',
        'click .spam': 'spam',
        'click .duplicate': 'duplicate'
    },
    verify: function(e) {
        id = e.currentTarget.id;
        table = new App.Models.Table({ id: id });
        table.urlRoot = this.url;
        table.fetch();
        table.toJSON();
        table.set('verified', 1);
        table.save();

    },
    spam: function(e) {
        ...

    },
    duplicate: function(e) {
            ...
    },
    remove: function() {
        this.$el.remove();
        console.log('hello');
    },
    retrieveTemplate: function(model) {
        return _.template($('#' + this.template).html(), model);
    },
    render: function() {
        //console.log(this);
        this.$el.html(this.retrieveTemplate(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
    }
});
```

As I understand it, `this.model.on('update', this.remove, this);` should call my remove function when `save` completes. But the callback isn't firing because I'm not getting the `console.log` and my DOM isn't being updated.  What am I doing wrong?  I followed a tutorial, but everything works fine in the tutorial.

Comment: I also tried `create` instead of `update` and still no luck.

Comment: table.toJSON();   -- that line of code isn't doing anything BTW. You need to do something with the JSON that it returns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `update` event. I think you mean `sync`

http://backbonejs.org/#Events-catalog

`"sync" (model, resp, options) — when a model has been successfully synced with the server.`

Also a helpful hit for debugging that I found was using the `all` event to see what events are getting triggered.

**Edit:**

After some debugging, the goal of the `verify()` function was to save the verified attribute to the model. To do that we needed to change `verify()` to

```
this.model.set('verified', 1);
this.model.save();
```

instead of creating a new `App.Model.Table` and setting it to the `table` variable. Doing `table` .save() was saving the **new** `table` model, instead of the old model, `this.model`. That's why the event handlers attached to `this.model` were net getting triggered.

Comment: I tried `this.model.on('sync', this.remove, this)`,  Is that correct?  It's not working.

Comment: maybe you are getting an error when you try to sync? in that case you would need to subscribe to the `error` event

Comment: Error doesn't work either.  I can see the successful PUT request.

Comment: All doesn't fire either.  There must be something more fundamental wrong.

Comment: Huh.. are you on version 0.9.9? if so I would try the `all` event. If that isn't getting hit it.... Not sure what it could be :(

Comment: Yeah, I'm on 0.9.9.  Okay, I'll keep digging.

Comment: Am I editing the right line of code in `this.model.on('sync', this.remove, this);`?

Comment: Oh, I think it has something to do with your verify code. you are saving on `table` which is a new model, and you are listing on `this.model` which is a different model.

Comment: THey're all supposed to fire off the same model.  Or is that possible?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22720/discussion-between-hajpoj-and-sehummel)

Answer (score 0):

There are no "create" or "update" events in Backbone.js. That's why your remove() callback isn't firing.

See http://backbonejs.org/#Events-catalog for a catalog of the possible events in Backbone.

***UPDATE***:

After looking at your code more closely, the answer is clear. They are different models:

```
initialize: function(options) {
    this.model.on('change', this.render, this);
    this.model.on('sync', this.remove, this);
```

and

```
table = new App.Models.Table({ id: id });
...
table.save();
```

The events that occur on your `table` object are not going to trigger event handlers that are bound to a totally different model (this.model).

Why create another model (table) when you already had a model? (this.model) ?

*** UPDATE ***

I don't really understand what you're trying to do, but perhaps try this:

```
table = new App.Models.Table({ id: id });
table.on('sync', this.remove, this);
```

Comment: OK.  Do I do `this.model.on('sync', this.remove, this);`?

Comment: @sehummel Yeah, that should get fired on a successul save(). If it's not getting fired, there must have been an error

Comment: Any thoughts on what it might be?  Maybe it's not seeing the model?

Comment: @sehummel  try this:   `table.save({}, {success: function(){ console.log('success');}, {error: function(){ console.log('error'); }});` to prove that it was successful

Comment: That makes sense.  Do I just remove the word "new"?

Comment: No, you need that when creating new models! But, I don't understand why you need to create a new model if you already have this.model. Anyway, see updated answer to see if that helps.